# EclipseLink/JPA: Specify length of byte array

Tags: java, sql, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I have the following definition:

```
@Column(name = "password", length = 80)
byte[] password;
```

When I use EclipseLink to create the tables (mysql) I get a table with a `longblob`. A `tinyblob` would suffice.

How do I have to specify the length?

I know that I could add a `columnDefinition` but I'd like to keep it database/sql agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want specific type for blob column, columnDefinition should be used. Problem with length is that it is only for strings. This is also told in [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#length%28%29).